# Can't use TransmitFile to Send data through Winsock

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock

I've got a complete Winsock client and server below. I'm not able to get the whole file though.

The client is not filling up its buffer with the data.

Stepping through debug it *looks* like the server process is sending back, but I only get three loops and the `recv()` is done.

I assume I'm missing something apparent, but not being fluent in Winsock or `memcpy`, can someone help me?

Single winsockserver.cpp code:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <mswsock.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Mswsock.lib")

WCHAR REGPATH[260];

BOOL SetPrivilege() 
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken) != 0)
        {
        LUID luid;
        BOOL bLookupPrivilegeValue = LookupPrivilegeValueW(NULL, L"SeBackupPrivilege", &luid);
        if (bLookupPrivilegeValue == TRUE)
            {
            TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
            tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
            tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
            tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
            BOOL bAdjustTokenPrivileges = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, (PDWORD)NULL);
            return ((bAdjustTokenPrivileges == TRUE) && (GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS));
            }
        }
    return TRUE;
}

SOCKET SetUpListener(CONST CHAR *pcAddress, INT nPort)
{
    DWORD dwWSA = 0;
    INT iBind = 0;
    ULONG nInterfaceAddr = 0;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, pcAddress, &nInterfaceAddr);
    if (nInterfaceAddr != INADDR_NONE) 
        {
        SOCKET sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sd != INVALID_SOCKET) 
            {
            sockaddr_in sinInterface;
            sinInterface.sin_family = AF_INET;
            sinInterface.sin_addr.s_addr = nInterfaceAddr;
            sinInterface.sin_port = nPort;            
            iBind = bind(sd, (sockaddr*) &sinInterface, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
            if (iBind != SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                listen(sd, SOMAXCONN);
                return sd;
                }
            dwWSA = WSAGetLastError();
            }
        }
    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}

BOOL ReceiveDoWorkThenReturnDataToClient(SOCKET sd)
{    
    CHAR acReadBuffer[1024];
    INT nReadBytes;
    do 
        {
        nReadBytes = recv(sd, acReadBuffer, 1024, 0);
        if (nReadBytes > 0) 
            {
            //INT nSentBytes = 0;
            //while (nSentBytes < nReadBytes) 
                {
                WCHAR* sTempFileOut = new WCHAR[MAX_PATH]();
                StringCchCopyW(sTempFileOut, MAX_PATH, L"c:\\temp\\~test.txt");

                HKEY key;
                LRESULT dresult = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REGPATH, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &key);  // If the function succeeds, the return value is ERROR_SUCCESS.
                if (dresult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                    {
                    DWORD dwErrorBackupPriv = 0;
                    if (SetPrivilege() == TRUE)
                        {
                        LSTATUS dStatus = RegSaveKeyW(key, sTempFileOut, NULL);  // If the function succeeds, the return value is ERROR_SUCCESS.
                        if ((dStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS) || (dStatus == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS))
                            {
                            HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(sTempFileOut, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
                            if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                                {
                                ULARGE_INTEGER ul;
                                ul.LowPart = GetFileSize(hFile, &ul.HighPart);

                                if ((ul.LowPart == INVALID_FILE_SIZE) && (GetLastError() != 0)) return 7;

                                OVERLAPPED ov = {};
                                ov.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
                                if (!ov.hEvent) return 8;

                                unsigned __int64 uiPos = 0;
                                unsigned __int64 uiRemaining = ul.QuadPart;

                                while (uiRemaining > 0)
                                    {
                                    ul.QuadPart = uiPos;
                                    ov.Offset = ul.LowPart;
                                    ov.OffsetHigh = ul.HighPart;
                                    DWORD dwNumToSend = (uiRemaining >= 3) ? 3 : (DWORD)uiRemaining;
                                    if (!TransmitFile(sd, hFile, dwNumToSend, 0, &ov, NULL, 0))
                                        {
                                        if ((GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) && (WSAGetLastError() != WSA_IO_PENDING))
                                            break;
                                        WaitForSingleObject(ov.hEvent, INFINITE);
                                        }

                                    uiPos += dwNumToSend;
                                    uiRemaining -= dwNumToSend;

                                    Sleep(100);
                                    }

                                CloseHandle(ov.hEvent);
                                CloseHandle(hFile);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                delete[] sTempFileOut;
                }
            }
        else if (nReadBytes == SOCKET_ERROR) 
            return FALSE;
        }
    while (nReadBytes != 0);
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL ShutdownConnection(SOCKET sd)
{
    if (shutdown(sd, SD_SEND) == SOCKET_ERROR) return FALSE;
    CHAR acReadBuffer[1024];
    while (1) 
        {
        INT nNewBytes = recv(sd, acReadBuffer, 1024, 0);
        if (nNewBytes == SOCKET_ERROR) return FALSE;
        else if (nNewBytes == 0) break;
        }
    return (closesocket(sd) != SOCKET_ERROR);
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadHandler(void* sd_)
{
    INT nRetval = 0;
    SOCKET sd = (SOCKET) sd_;
    if (!ReceiveDoWorkThenReturnDataToClient(sd)) nRetval = 3;
    if (!ShutdownConnection(sd)) nRetval = 4;
    return nRetval;
}

unsigned WINAPI ListenAndAccept(void *)
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    INT nCode;    
    sockaddr_in sinRemote;
    INT nAddrSize = sizeof(sinRemote);
    DWORD nThreadID;

    if ((nCode = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsaData)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) return nCode;
    SOCKET ListeningSocket = SetUpListener("localhost", htons(43210));
    if (ListeningSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return 3;
    while (1)
        {
        SOCKET sd = accept(ListeningSocket, (sockaddr*)&sinRemote, &nAddrSize);
        if (sd != INVALID_SOCKET)
            CreateThread(0, 0, &ThreadHandler, (void*)sd, 0, &nThreadID);
        else
            break;
        }
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    UINT threadID = 0;
    StringCchCopy(REGPATH, 260, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Direct3D");
    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &ListenAndAccept, NULL, 0, &threadID);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);

    while (1)
        ;
}
```

Single Winsockclient.cpp file:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mswsock.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <windns.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <windns.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dnsapi.lib")

DWORD SendWinsockCommandToRemoteServer(CONST DWORD dwCharsAllocatedReturnString, WCHAR **sStringReturned)
{
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    INT recvbuflen = 65536;
    DWORD dwIPv4 = 0;
    DWORD dwErr = 0;

    SecureZeroMemory(*sStringReturned, dwCharsAllocatedReturnString * sizeof(CHAR));
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
        return WSAGetLastError();

    sockaddr_in clientService{};
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = dwIPv4;
    clientService.sin_port = htons(43210);

    INT iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService));
    if ((iResult != 0) || (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR))
        {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        return WSAGetLastError();
        }

    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, "test", 5, 0);
    if ((iResult == INVALID_SOCKET) || (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR))
        {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        return 5;
        }

    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        return 6;
        }

    DWORD dwLen = 0;    
    BYTE * cRecvbuf = (BYTE*) calloc(65536, sizeof(BYTE));
    BYTE * cRecvbuf2 = (BYTE*) calloc(65536, sizeof(BYTE));
    do 
        {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, (CHAR *) cRecvbuf, recvbuflen, MSG_WAITALL);
        memcpy(cRecvbuf2, cRecvbuf, sizeof(cRecvbuf)*2);
        }
    while (iResult > 0);

    DWORD dwLenOfRecvbuf = strlen((CHAR *) cRecvbuf);
    if (dwLenOfRecvbuf > 0)
        dwLen = dwLenOfRecvbuf + 1;

    if (dwLen > 0)
        {
        WCHAR *sRecvbuf = new WCHAR[dwLen]();
        DWORD dwCharWrittenToBuffer = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (CHAR*)cRecvbuf, (INT)dwLen, sRecvbuf, dwLen);
        if (dwCharWrittenToBuffer != 0)
            StringCchCopyW(*sStringReturned, dwLen, sRecvbuf);
        delete[] sRecvbuf;
        free(cRecvbuf);
        if (dwCharWrittenToBuffer == 0)
            return 7;
        }
    else
        {
        free(cRecvbuf);
        return 8;
        }

    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    return 0;
}


void QueryWinsockServer(CONST DWORD dwDataAllocatedSize, WCHAR** sDataBack, DWORD* dwErrorFromSendWinsockCommandToRemoteServer)
{
    SecureZeroMemory(*sDataBack, dwDataAllocatedSize * sizeof (WCHAR));
    WCHAR *sRV = new WCHAR[dwDataAllocatedSize]();
    *dwErrorFromSendWinsockCommandToRemoteServer = SendWinsockCommandToRemoteServer(dwDataAllocatedSize, &sRV);
    if (*dwErrorFromSendWinsockCommandToRemoteServer == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
        DWORD dwLenToCopy = wcslen(sRV) + 1;
        StringCchCopyW(*sDataBack, dwLenToCopy, sRV);
        }
    delete[] sRV;
}




int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    DWORD dwDataAllocatedSize = 1024;
    DWORD dwErr = 0;
    WCHAR* sData = new WCHAR[dwDataAllocatedSize]();
    WSADATA wsaData{};

    INT iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    QueryWinsockServer(dwDataAllocatedSize, &sData, &dwErr);

    wprintf(L"Press any key to end.");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This might not be the only problem, but why are you calling `TransmitFile` repeatedly to send 3-byte chunks?  Just pass `dwNumBytes` as zero and let it do its thing, see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-transmitfile).

Comment: I"m trying to send a binary file from server to client. Good suggestion, I'll try that. The client receiving the BYTE string, `recv()` only accepts `CHAR *`, so that might be an issue why `recv()` is only being run 3 times?

Comment: Not using Transmit...solution found in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634483/send-binary-file-over-tcp-ip-connection, post by @RemyLebeau

Comment: Oh, OK, but it should be possible to get `TransmitFile` to work - it is purpose designed for the job.  Then again, if you want portable code...

Comment: It's just for Windows, so if `TransmitFile` would work better, then yeah, I just don't have the right code on the server or client side, and finding working example code for `TransmitFile` is a wee bit difficult!

Comment: @JeffR Possible duplicate of [TransmitFile sending the same bytes again and again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706315/). Oh, nevermind, I see you are the one who commented on my answer to that question, so you are now trying to adopt that code into your project and failing. I agree with PaulSanders, the best way to use `TransmitFile` is to let it transmit the entire file in one go, not break it up into 3-byte chunks (you may as well just use `send()` for that). You should send the file size, then transmit the file. Receive the file size, then read until the full size is received.

Comment: Why memcpy and ignore the destination buffer? Why strlen on file data that might be binary?